# Wrap multiple lines of text with different sibling tags in Emmet

Tags: html, emmet

Is there a way using Emmet to highlight and wrap the following lines:

```
This is a title
This is a subtitle
This is the sentence below the subtitle.
```

So that it would output:

```
<h2>This is a title</h2>
<h3>This is a subtitle</h3>
<p>This is the sentence below the subtitle.</p>
```

I've tried:

```
h2+h3+p
```

But that outputs:

```
<h2></h2>
<h3></h3>
<p>This is a titleThis is a subtitleThis is the sentence below the subtitle.</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
h2{This is a title}+h3{This is a subtitle}+p{This is the sentence below the subtitle.}
```

JS Fiddle: (Just press tab at the end of the line :)

http://jsbin.com/qelenuda/1/edit

Comment: I want to be able to highlight the lines of text and apply the styles.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: Select the multiple lines with my cursor and wrap them with the desired tags. Here's the Emmet documentation on what I mean: http://docs.emmet.io/actions/wrap-with-abbreviation/

Comment: Where are you using emmet? An editor? JSFiddle/JSbin? An IDE? Some of these features may work on one place but not another.

Comment: Primarily PHPStorm but also with Sublime Text 2

Answer (score 0):

No, it’s not possible. In this case it’s much faster to individually wrap each line instead of struggling with new syntax for single abbreviation.